# asp.net mvc modelbinding for username and date

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a logging controller in my project that gets Log data from javascript client side and sends to server.

Log Model ils like this.

```
public class Log
{
    public string Event { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

My controller action is like this.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Save(Log log)
    {
        log.Username = User.Identity.Name;
        log.Date = DateTime.now;

        return Json(new { message = "ok" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

when users sended the log data, I need to set the username and date. Is there another way with model binding or else? Automatically set the context.username and date time of log.

Comment: What is the reason behind this? Your current solution looks fine. I tossed a +1 on the answer below as it explains that doing it that way is actually a bit confusing and IMO will just cause trouble. I don't understand why you need to use model binding for this problem.

Comment: I have a little model else this. So I need set these properties for saving. For example: Comment, Query, SomeService models has action time and username. I want to set them everytime .

Answer (score 1):

`IModelBinder` is the preferred way to go. You implement the interface and register it in Global.asax file

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Log), new LogModelBinder());
```

What I don't like about this approach is that you have to be aware that there is a custom model binder for this type implemented somewhere and it can cause confusion if you forget about it, or you have a new developer working on the project and model starts behaving strange. It is just not obvious enough what is changing the object.

I like to have all my custom logic implemented in the controller itself. You can override `OnActionExecuting` and inject the properties there, better yet, have a `BaseController` that all your controllers inherit from and do your custom logic in there.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    object model = filterContext.ActionParameters
                                .TryGetValue("model", out model) 
                                ? model : null;
    if (model != null)
    {
        var logModel = model as Log;
        if (logModel != null)
        {
            logModel.Date = DateTime.Now;
            logModel.Username = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you change that "null" to "new object()", I believe you can skip that first null check.

Comment: @Graham I can skip first if check even now because if model is null it will still return false when I call `model as Log`, but this is the convention I like to follow. (In this case, do something only if you have the model)